# ValueError issue and how to extract not matching strings from two files?

Tags: python, spyder, valueerror

Hello everyone and thanks in advance.

I'm trying to extract the not matching column strings from two different csv files and write the results in a new cvs file.

As far as now, I've written this code:

```
import csv

with open(r'C:\Users\DataAnalyst\Desktop\phonesdata\sms_03.csv', 'r') as sms:
    sms_indices = dict((r[1], i) for i, r in enumerate(csv.reader(sms)))


with open(r'C:\Users\DataAnalyst\Desktop\phonesdata\marketing.csv', 'r') as marketing:
      reader = csv.reader(marketing)
      f3 = open('results.csv', 'w')
      c3 = csv.writer(f3)     


sms_mark = list(marketing)

for sms_03_row in sms:
    row = 1
    found = False
    results_row = sms_03_row  #Moved out from nested loop
    for marketing_row in sms_mark:        
        x = marketing[0]
        if sms_03_row[1] != marketing_row[0]:
            results_row.append(x)
            found = True
            break
    row += 1
    if not found:
        results_row.append('Not found')     
    c3.writerow(results_row)

sms.close()
marketing.close()
f3.close()
```

However, I got this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

   File "<ipython-input-5-bc26b28cdf70>", line 1, in <module>
     sms_mark = list(marketing)

ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

How can I solved it? Having this code, will I get just the not matching strings?

Thank you!

Comment: Looks like you have an indentation issue.

Comment: how can I solved that? thank you!

Comment: I have fixed the indentation. You also don't need to explicitly close each file in the end. The `with` statement does that for you automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have there some indentadion issues. Anyway let the `with` statement take care about opening and closing files and you will be fine:

```
import csv

with open(r'<path_to_sms>', 'r') as sms, open(r'<path_to_marketing>') as marketing,
     open(r'results.csv', 'w') as f3:
    sms_indices = dict((r[1], i) for i, r in enumerate(csv.reader(sms)))
    reader = csv.reader(marketing)
    c3 = csv.writer(f3)

    sms_mark = list(marketing)
    results_row = []
    # your stuff goes here
    c3.writerow(results_row)
```

Comment: First of all: Thank you for your help! However, when I tried your code, it retrieves me this issue: sms_indices = dict((r[1], i) for i, r in enumerate(csv.reader(sms)))
    ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level    What could it be? thanks again!!!

Comment: @proma It is intendation problem again. You must decide wheter you want to use spaces or tabs for intendation. Everything within "with statement" should be intended for example with for spaces.